# Error occurs when I run my react native project on an android real device

Tags: react-native

The following error occurs when I run my react native project on an android real device.

```
Unexpected Identifier 'cat' try statements must have at least a catch or finally block no stack
```

How do I solve it ?

Comment: seems like a typo, you might have mispelled `catch` as `cat`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share some code where this is happening

The error says that somewhere in your code you have `try {}` statement without `catch {}` or `finally {}`

To fix it search where you have `try` statements and add `catch` or `finally` to it.

Example:

```js
try {
  // Some code
} catch (error) {
  // Handle error
} finally {
  // On finish
}
```

Comment: No I don't use ( try , catch ) block, in my codes